# How can I use GetAsyncKeyState to implement a global hotkey?

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I have created simple program that can capture key pressing globally on windows. i have used `GetAsyncKeyState()`. this is my code.

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Integer) As Short

For i = 65 To 128
    If GetAsyncKeyState(i) = -32767 Then
        return Chr(i)
    End If
Next i
```

It works properly. but if i run another application used `GetAsyncKeyState()`, together my program (or two instance of my program) key capturing is does not work correctly. it capture some of keys, not all. 
for example; if I typed "stackoverflow" it capture "sakvrow"

where is the poblem and how can I fix it.

Comment: The return value of the function contains *bits*, it isn't just -32767.  Test for < 0 instead.  A very serious problem with the approach is that how well it works critically depend on how often you call this function.  Call it too quickly and you'll see the same key still down.  Call it not quickly enough and you'll just miss keys.  Your current problem.  You cannot make this work reliably, use a low-level keyboard hook instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I have use **Timer** with 1 **interval**

Comment: @HansPassant This program work correctly on word or any other applications but it does not work on excel because excel exe also use `GetAsyncKeyState()` that's my problem. I cant understand what's the reason for that.

Comment: I warned you about the return value.  Bit #0 is set when the key was pressed since the previous call.  So your code *accidentally* got a mismatch on -32767, it is -32766 if the bit is set.  Sure, other code calling GetAsyncKeyState() as well is going to alter that, bit #0 is clear again when you call it.  There certainly is more than one way in which this code will malfunction, it is simply the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: where is the poblem?

The problem is explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx):

Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, **another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application**. The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and **should not be relied upon**.

Q:how can I fix it?

As Hans suggested in comments, if you want some sort of "keylogger", you should use a keybord hook. See [WH_KEYBOARD_LL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

put a `textbox` to see the events 
you have to add a `timer` set `interval` to 100 enable it put this code on it

```
Dim result As Integer
    For i = 1 To 255
        result = 0
        result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
        If result = -32767 Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Chr(i)
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Jum is not very happy with our answser :-)